# Multiple consumers based on consumer record key in spring boot kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to list kafka topic based on the consumer record key. Right now I have consumer and based on the condition I am processing the record

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerStringContainerFactory")
public void listenasString(ConsumerRecord<String, String> cr) {
  if (cr.key().equals("A")) {
    //do some processing
  } else if (cr.key().equals("B")) {
    //do some processing
  }

}
```

Is it possible to have multiple consumers to listen to same topic based on the key?

Comment: what do you mean  listen to same topic based on the key? why do you want to do that ?

Comment: Its the requirement , we can have same data with different keys. Based on the key I have to do different processing

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want is possible

> have multiple consumers to listen to same topic

Yes, this is possible

> based on the key

This is not, because a key is not a queryable. You would need to compute **the partition of that key**, then you would need to assign the consumer *to that partition*.

Outside of Spring, you can initialize `DefaultPartitioner` and use `consumer.assign` to make this work

From there I would suggest using one consumer thread per partition, and your secondary if statements would need to move unless there's multiple keys in the same partitions (which is possible)

Comment: Thee only way I can think you can do it is, if you have as many partitions as there are keys, and a custom `Partitioner` to route each key to its own partition; you would then set the container concurrency to the number of partitions so each consumer gets one partition.

Comment: @Gary but even then, you can't guarantee which thread/instance gets which key, so you'd end up with a large if-else block checking all possible keys, right?

Comment: That is true; there is no way to avoid that with one topic. You would need a topic per key and a `@KafkaListener` per topic to avoid that.

Comment: Although you can manually assign individual partitions to `@KafkaListener` methods rather than using group management.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions, for now we are going with if else approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams to create two topics based on keys and run a consumer for each of these topics. But if you want that to be in the same topic then @criket_007 answer is correct, this is not possible.

Check Kafka Stream Branch https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#stateless-transformations